# How can one stipulate the width (visible columns) of a displayed dataset?

Tags: dataset

In perusing MSA, I note that one can control the number of rows that are visible in a dataset by using the command:

```
 Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount = n;
```

where n can be set to the desired number of rows.

Although there appears to be a corresponding way to set the number visible columns, since Dataset`$DatasetTargetColumnCount appears in black when entered and the following expression generates no error,

```
 Dataset`$DatasetTargetColumnCount = 14
```

it doesn't work (using Ver. 13.1.0.0).  This is the case even though for the dataset I am interested in displaying fullscreen there appears to be ample room to do so as seems  evidenced by the width of another dataset with fewer columns but with relatively long strings in some columns).

**Is there a way to do this?**  It's a bit awkward to have to scroll back and forth.  Is there perhaps some documentation regarding the `$Dataset context that I have been unable to locate?  Perhaps the command would work if FontSize could be set to a smaller font, but I have been unable to discover the correct syntax to try.  There appears to be no

```
Dataset`$DatasetFontSize =n
```

Comment: Have you tried the `MaxItems` option for `Dataset`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  However, the number of "items" in my dataset is 12, but setting MaxItems->12 fails to over-ride the number of columns displayed, which is still 10.  Perhaps, there is a way to increase the overall underlying "page size" so that the maximum number of characters displayed on a single line is large enough to accommodate the 2 additional columns.  Visually, there appears to be space on the display but this space is not being utilized in the generation of the grid being displayed.

Comment: Since the dataset is built via using AssociationThread, I thought I could use Style first on the labels (ie from First) and then Style on the data (ie from Rest).  However, although the both the list of labels and the data are in fact displayed in a smaller font, Dataset seems to ignore this change in style and creates a grid with the first column name as row labels and the all the data values for that row as a list, albeit in a smaller font in a second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SetOptions[Dataset, MaxItems -> {m, n}]` where `m` is the max rows and `n` max columns.

Comment: Works like a charm.